# Toggle days on and off in a calendar view?

Tags: fullcalendar

I need to store the 'on' days (in this case, the 'available' days) in the database and show the 'available' days on a monthly or weekly view.

I need to allow a user to toggle days on a the calendar on and off.  I've been looking a [fullcalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) and some bootstrap options such as http://bootstrap-calendar.azurewebsites.net/.

With Fullcalendar, is there a way to toggle a day on and off in a weekly or monthly view? and generate the corresponding AJAX call?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can use [background events](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_rendering/Background_Events/) to show that a day is available or not available. And [`dayClick`](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/mouse/dayClick/) to toggle it back and forth. Since background events are events, they should store and fetch from the DB.

Keep in mind, that all this needs to be coded though. It doesn't automatically code a day toggle. But these things aren't too difficult or long to code and FC is built to facilitate this kind of thing.